# How do I control the direction in which my UILabel Expands?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, uilabel

I have several Buttons each with three UILabels alongside them, half of these buttons two labels to the left as shown below. Each label has a number within it between 1 and 3 digits and will expand (using the UIView method 'sizeToFit') to fit this number. However when the labels are on the left the view overlaps the button when it expands. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting I'd rather not fix my UILabels size and set the text to align to the right as I wish to keep my labels background black.

Comment: The two labels aligned to the left of the button in the picture above are fine when they're 0 or one digit long, anymore than that and they overlap the button. I'd rather that the labels expands to the left when the number within it gets larger so there is no overlap.

Comment: So you have solved your own problem?

Comment: @sunkehappy No because I don't know how to expand the labels to the left. It's what my question is asking!

Comment: So you want to show your label almost on the left of your button?

Comment: I want the right hand side of the label aligned with the left hand side of the label at all times regardless of the size of the number. Yet I want the label to be expandable.

Comment: I think you can compute your label's size and move it to the left of your button. Or I misunderstand you?